# list bibliographic references in order of citation occurrence

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have included my references in the following way:

```
\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}   
...
\bibliography{refs}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

And my refs.bib file has an entry like this:

```
@article{Suhai,
author = {Suhai, S.},
journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
volume = 27,
year = 1983,
pages = {3506-18},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.27.3506}
}
```

The link from the url-entry works perfectly fine when I compile a PDF document, however the references are in alphabetical order. But what I want is the order of occurrence in the document. I usually do that with

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

However, then the links do not work anymore.

Is there a way to get both?

Comment: If you change `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`, the order in which references are cited will correspond to the order in which they appear in the References and the url's remain active hyperlinks.

Comment: Thanks, that works. If you like to write an answer I could mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` is a bibliography style provided with the `natbib` package. Its use ensures that functionality introduced by `natbib` is available for formating references. It is required here, in combination with `hyperref`, to get the same ordering of citations in the document body and in the list of references. The URL's are retained with active hyperlinks.

This is demonstrated by the following MWE and the output that follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{Suhai,
    author = {Suhai, S.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    volume = 27,
    year = 1983,
    pages = {3506-18},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.27.3506}
}

@article{Zuhai,
    author = {Zuhai, S.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    volume = 27,
    year = 1983,
    pages = {3506-18},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.27.3506}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \cite{Zuhai}

    \cite{Suhai}
    \bibliography{refs}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\end{document}
```

[image]